# centering content using flex in safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, center

I have some problem using flex in safari. When i try to centering content in input, it has some strange effect:

[image: strange effect]

CSS is

```
input[type=submit] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 386px;
    height: 47px;
    margin: auto auto 0;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d08b4d;
    border-radius: 24px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

The same code i apply to div's, it's ok, content has central position in block.
Html of that part of code

```
<form>
<h3 class="form-title">Send a message</h3>
<input type="text" name="name" title="name" placeholder="Name" required>
<input type="email" name="email" title="email" placeholder="Email" required>
<textarea name="message" id="" title="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

With another browsers i dont have any prombles, both mobile and desktop. This code was tested on safari > 7. 
Is there some native css solution?

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for this issue on safari 9.1.2 and what helped me to center items was the old 2009 Flexbox specification:

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center; /* justify-content */
-webkit-box-align: center; /* align-items */
```

Try to remove `display: flex;` and see if it works for you.